# Table populated from calculations from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, one called **AcreMultiplier**, and one called **Land**. I am trying to create calculations to populate a third table named **Allotment**.

For better understanding, the Land table contains MapTaxLots(MapTaxIDs), which is a section of land. I then have customers who can own many of these MapTaxLots. Each MapTaxLot has the ability to contain different types of Acres such as KID, KBID, Warren, GroupE, CalD, and Rent. Each type of acre has an associated amount as well.

[image: Land Table]

Each type of acre has a multiplier in the AcreMultiplier table. This multiplier will be used to create a total allotment for every customer.

The calculation needs to go through every MapTaxID and multiply each type of acre (KID, KBID, Warren, GroupE, CalD, and Rent) by the multiplier in the AcreMultiplier table. However, I need to add up the entire equation for each customer as a total Allotmnet for the Allotment table. My entire query should insert CustomerID, and Allotment for now.

I currently tried something like this, but I am new to inserting data using calculations based on other tables.

[image: My current query]

If you can suggest any ideas or even help me with my current query, I would be very thankful.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: here is a way to ask question :http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm new here. That doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Post says : provide some sample test data ,along with what you have atleast attempted and what is the output

Comment: If you looked at my photo links, you would have seen that I did that.

Comment: + Im limited to 2 photos, so I explained everything as well as I could....

Comment: We can't copy and paste photos into our own tools, so photos are generally not useful to us. [Edit] your question and include the data as *text* that we *can* copy & paste and manipulate. (Ideally, put it inside `{}` code blocks to maintain a tabular layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be best if the `Land` table were split into two separate tables: the first for which CustomerID is associated with each MapTaxID, the second for what types/amounts of Acres each MapTaxID has. Then, the solution is a lot simpler.

However, assuming you wouldn't be able to do that, here's a solution that should work for you (assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or later):

```
-- Recreate your tables
CREATE TABLE #Land 
  (
     [CustomerID]        INT NOT NULL,
     [MapTaxID]          INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [AcresAmountKID]    DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     [AcresAmountKBID]   DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     [AcresAmountWarren] DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     [AcresAmountGroupE] DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     [AcresAmountCalD]   DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     [AcresAmountRent]   DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
  )
CREATE TABLE #AcreMultiplier
  (
     [AcreTypeID]       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     [MultiplierAmount] DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
  )

-- Populate with random data
INSERT INTO #Land
            ([CustomerID],
             [AcresAmountKID],
             [AcresAmountKBID],
             [AcresAmountWarren],
             [AcresAmountGroupE],
             [AcresAmountCalD],
             [AcresAmountRent])
VALUES      (1,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (2,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (2,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (2,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (2,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (3,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30),
            (3,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30,RAND() * 30)

INSERT INTO #AcreMultiplier
            ([AcreTypeID],
             [MultiplierAmount])
VALUES      ('KID',RAND() * 5),
            ('KBID',RAND() * 5),
            ('Warren',RAND() * 5),
            ('GroupE',RAND() * 5),
            ('CalD',RAND() * 5),
            ('Rent',RAND() * 5)

-- Let's see what we have
SELECT *
FROM   #Land

SELECT *
FROM   #AcreMultiplier
```

We can UNPIVOT `Land` (i.e. take each `AcresAmount` column and "create" a row for each one) and join to `AcreMultiplier`:

```
SELECT upvt.[CustomerID],
       upvt.[MapTaxID],
       [Allotment] = SUM(upvt.[AcreAmount] * am.[MultiplierAmount])
FROM   #Land l
       UNPIVOT ( [AcreAmount]
               FOR [AcreTypeID] IN ([AcresAmountKID],
                                    [AcresAmountKBID],
                                    [AcresAmountWarren],
                                    [AcresAmountGroupE],
                                    [AcresAmountCalD],
                                    [AcresAmountRent])) upvt
       JOIN #AcreMultiplier am
         ON REPLACE(upvt.[AcreTypeID], 'AcresAmount', '') = am.[AcreTypeID]
GROUP  BY upvt.[CustomerID],
          upvt.[MapTaxID] 


SELECT upvt.[CustomerID],
       [Allotment] = SUM(upvt.[AcreAmount] * am.[MultiplierAmount])
FROM   #Land l
       UNPIVOT ( [AcreAmount]
               FOR [AcreTypeID] IN ([AcresAmountKID],
                                    [AcresAmountKBID],
                                    [AcresAmountWarren],
                                    [AcresAmountGroupE],
                                    [AcresAmountCalD],
                                    [AcresAmountRent])) upvt
       JOIN #AcreMultiplier am
         ON REPLACE(upvt.[AcreTypeID], 'AcresAmount', '') = am.[AcreTypeID]
GROUP  BY upvt.[CustomerID]
```

Assuming your data is not too big, it might be best to simply run this query or create a `VIEW` rather than populate a new `TABLE`. Otherwise, the table could get out-of-date, etc.

Comment: You are absolutely amazing man! The unpivot function is exactly what I needed! I've never done functions such as this. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way I can get your email? I need to create a function similar to the last one where I insert this into the empty table. And then I need to implement this function into my ASP.net web application so I can insert every time a multiplier is changed.

Comment: @Cels - Are you sure you need to populate a table? Could you use a [view](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/views.php) instead? A view saves your query as a "virtual table" that you can SELECT from. The benefit is that if the data in your underlying tables (`Land` and `AcreMultiplier`) changes, the view would change _automatically_ - because it's just a query.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have to do it this way to calculate new values from this data. Every year, the Allotment table will be dropped and recreated from within the ASP.net web application.